# No implementation for: ->fill_pattern

Tags: xpce

estoy tratando de dibujar un teclado usando XPCE.

Este es mi codigo:

```
:- use_module(library(pce)).

draw_keyboard :-
    new(Window, picture('Keyboard')),
    send(Window, size, size(600, 200)),
    send(Window, open),
    draw_keys(Window).

draw_keys(Window) :-
    % Define el ancho y alto de cada tecla
    KeyWidth = 30,
    KeyHeight = 100,
    % Define los colores para las teclas blancas y negras
    WhiteColor = white,
    BlackColor = black,
    % Define la posición inicial de la primera tecla
    KeyX = 10,
    KeyY = 50,
    % Dibuja las teclas blancas
    draw_white_keys(Window, KeyX, KeyY, KeyWidth, KeyHeight, WhiteColor, 1),
    % Dibuja las teclas negras
    draw_black_keys(Window, KeyX, KeyY, KeyWidth, KeyHeight, BlackColor, 1).

draw_white_keys(_, _, _, _, _, _, 9).
draw_white_keys(Window, KeyX, KeyY, KeyWidth, KeyHeight, Color, N) :-
    % Dibuja una tecla blanca
    new(Key, graphical(0, 0, KeyWidth, KeyHeight)),
    send(Key, fill_pattern, Color),
    send(Key, move, point(KeyX, KeyY)),
    send(Window, display, Key),
    % Calcula la posición de la siguiente tecla
    NextX is KeyX + KeyWidth,
    % Dibuja la siguiente tecla blanca
    N1 is N + 1,
    draw_white_keys(Window, NextX, KeyY, KeyWidth, KeyHeight, Color, N1).

draw_black_keys(_, _, _, 7).
draw_black_keys(Window, KeyX, KeyY, KeyWidth, KeyHeight, Color, N) :-
    % Calcula la posición de la tecla negra
    BlackKeyX is KeyX + KeyWidth - (KeyWidth / 4),
    BlackKeyY is KeyY - (KeyHeight / 2),
    % Dibuja una tecla negra
    new(Key, graphical(0, 0)),
    send(Key, fill_pattern, Color),
    send(Key, size, size(KeyWidth / 2, KeyHeight / 2)),
    send(Key, move, point(BlackKeyX, BlackKeyY)),
    send(Window, display, Key),
    % Calcula la posición de la siguiente tecla negra
    NextX is KeyX + KeyWidth,
    N1 is N + 1,
    % Si la siguiente tecla negra es la tercera o la séptima, deja un espacio
    (N1 =:= 3 ; N1 =:= 7 ->
        NextX1 is NextX + (KeyWidth / 2)
    ;
        NextX1 is NextX
    ),
    % Dibuja la siguiente tecla negra
    draw_black_keys(Window, NextX1, KeyY, KeyWidth, KeyHeight, Color, N1).
```

pero al tratar de correrlo obtengo el siguiente error

> ERROR: @12614202/graphical: No implementation for: ->fill_pattern

lo cual es muy extraño ya que se puede hallar en [la literatura](https://manualzz.com/doc/o/nurvg/xpce---swi-graphics), como en el [codigo de xpce](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/packages-xpce/blob/04d27192393d6c83ba4327657cbba8b1c54030ae/prolog/lib/pce_arrow_item.pl)

como puedo corregir el error?